# .NEt 4.5 not finding dll in GAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, gac

Let me explain the context before asking my question. I have a window 10 PC in which I'm the admin and I'm working in a ASP.NET 4.5 MVC solution. Now, I have to create a new user in this machine so he has a separated windows profile (as system admin as well). It was done but when I log with this user and open my Visual Studio solution I can't compile the project because most of the `Microsoft.CSharp`, `System`, etc.. references are missing.

[image]

[image]

I understand that they cannot be found in the GAC. This happens for most of the project within this solution but there is one that can find the references. I looked at the `.csproj` file and I don't see major differences in it.

I'm lost on what to do to solve this, this happens only for this new profile I created. In this profile I installed the .net SDK to try to solve and nothing.

Can you give me some clues to solve this issue?
Thanks for any help

Comment: The GAC is used at runtime, not compile-time, so all GAC talk is just a red herring. Please read [ask] and show the actual compiler warnings and errors and your research towards them, not just your interpretation of them.

Comment: OK, so what could explain the compiling in one profile and fail in another? I redo the references and it didn't work as well

Comment: Please show Output logs of build or something that we can use to help you.

Comment: @Juan They are all messages like this: The referenced component 'System.Xml' could not be found.

Comment: What's the reference pointing to? Is it a path? It kind of sounds like the .NET version you are trying to compile against is not available.

Comment: I will check if I have the version installed in this profile. I added the screenshots to my question

Comment: As CodeCaster said, projects are not compiled vs the actual assemblies, but rather vs. the reference assemblies. These should be located in %programfiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework  , in a subfolder like "v4.6.2" or whatever version the project targets. Would check if those are present and accessible.

Comment: They're broken references: try right clicking on the solution in solution explorer, and click "Restore NuGet Packages"